# Should I manually select protocol and cipher?

Tags: tls, cipher-selection

I'm writing Java code for a decentralized network.  (Proof of concept code [here](https://github.com/Erhannis/TlsChannelTest).)  Each node generates its own self-signed certificate, to be used both server-side and client-side in every connection.  Current key choice is 4096 bit RSA.  I figured I'd use TLSv1.3, since AFAICT that's most secure (though only marginally moreso than TLSv1.2).  I get an `sslContext` via `SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3")`.  I notice, though, that once I call `SSLEngine se = sslContext.createSSLEngine()`, `se.getEnabledProtocols()` returns "TLSv1.3", "TLSv1.2", and "SSLv2Hello".  Is it advisable to set the enabled protocols strictly to TLSv1.3, since I control both sides of the connection?  Or would that expose me to surprise bugs/vulnerabilities/whatever?

On a similar note, should I / should I not pick a specific set of enabled cipher suites?

Comment: Forcing TLS1.3 if you control both server and client is good practice.